# Are these correct reasons for rejection?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, rejected-edits, rejection-reasons

I removed [cobol](/questions/tagged/cobol) this morning from this post: [How to do Delete/Define with using IDCAMS using batch JCL (z/VSE)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18524246/how-to-do-delete-define-in-jcl-using-idcams-z-vse-os)

I got three rejections all saying:

> This edit is incorrect or an attempt to reply to or comment on the existing post.

Am I missing something?

Is the problem the comment for the edit reason? Tagging it COBOL was only one problem with the topic/post. I didn't expect it to last long, so didn't worry about the capitalization and other stuff (even the "coding").

The "correct" way to write JCL is to one's own site standards. The "correct" way to define VSAM files is to one's own site standards. Asking and taking stuff from the internet is going to be a waste of time/cause trouble. Rats, I'm going to get the "two questions in one" problem if I continue down that route...

So, can a suggested edit be rejected due to the comment on the edit? Either by rule, or accepted practice?

[image: Editd screenshot]

I've now looked at the Close flag. Doesn't seem that that is going to happen. If it is like Cricket and the benefit of the doubt goes to the poster (batsman), then a flag to close is going to be tricky. JCL is a tool. IDCAMS is a tool. The fact that no Mainframe site is going to be happy for their people to just toss stuff from the internet into their systems doesn't fit within the Help Centre thing. Just edit the lot and comment I suppose :-)

Yoy, now I've edited it again and got some extra Reputation. Feels a little unjust, but I'm sure it'll offset against losing something unjustly somewhere.

For a one-second tag-deletion, this is too much :-)

Comment: Tip: do not leave review summaries like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/18524246/3). Explain what you did and why, that's all that's necessary.

Comment: If it's not a good question, with no way to make it fit for SO, why waste the time to edit it? Just flag to close.

Comment: If anything I'd see that being rejected as too minor, but that choice of rejection reason seems odd to me...

Comment: Mat, Adinia OK. I didn't realise I could "flag" for close (it is kind of hidden, I now discover).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The rejection itself is valid. The post had a lot of other problems and you chose to improve only one part of it. I would have rejected the edit as too minor.

Also, from your question, I believe you are misinterpreting this rejection reason :

> This edit is incorrect or an attempt to reply to or comment on the existing post.

This means that either the edit is incorrect, addition of wrong information, breaking something else, etc. or that the edit is in response to a comment under the question or on one of the answer.

It does not mean that your [edit summary](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/18524246/3) needs to be more descriptive of the problem you think the post has.

Comment: OK. I now understand the use of the word "minor" in this context. Seems wrong, but there we go. First tags I edited, there was an option to change just the tags. Didn't get the implication of the removal of this option.